# An mobile app that jumps when the user press the call/send button in the smartphone

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, phone-call

I would like to develop an app for android and windows phone that calling button causes the application to run when the user press the dial/call button in his smartphone.

1. Is it possible with windows phone? if yes, how?
2. What is the function in Android that I can use with to push my app when the user press the call button.
3. If someone know application that work that way, I would be very happy for some links for that kind of mobile apps you know.

Comment: Like XepterX saying, What do you mean by the word JUMP here?

Comment: "JUMP" = calling button causes the application to run

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak on behalf of Android phones, but in Windows Phone, this is not possible as the OS/SDK does not allow a third party app to intercept any calls made from the phone, hence not possible in Windows Phone

Comment: Absolutely, positively, correct. Thank God Windows Phone is more secure than Android.